What does the triple arrow dash ability actually do?
I purchased the first dash upgrade from the Dash Master (icon is three arrows pointing up).

What does it actually do? I can’t tell. I think I dash faster, and when I do the dash trio that’s in the short ability sample video (not provided here), a thin white bar appears in the top left and reduces very slightly. I don’t notice any other effects.
What’s happening here? Am I missing something? What’s the bar, and what is it used for?

That icon is for Chain Dash, while the others are Bullet Absorb and Dash Attack.

Within certain frames, the Drifter can dash multiple times in quick succession when pressing the dash button after purchasing this upgrade.

Source, Abilities and Upgrades.
